# How to go back to previous when doing find replace confirm in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

Frequently when I am doing a find and replace in `vi` I will do it like this:

```
:%s/find/replace/gc
```

This gives you the option to skip by pressing `n`, or replace by pressing `y`.  But, sometimes I will accidentally skip over one in a large file by pressing `n` when I meant to press `y`.

How do I go backwards to the previous one and give me a second change?

Essentially, how to I `find` (`search`) the other direction temporarily? thanks.

Comment: happens in `vim` too

Comment: Note that `Shift + N` DOES NOT WORK :)

Comment: In substitution confirmation mode only the triggers `(y,n,q,l,a,^E,^Y)` keys work.

Comment: you might find **paxdiablo's** reply helpful in [Interactive search/replace regex in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505848/interactive-search-replace-regex-in-vim), this would allow you to use `Shift + N` as you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @ImranAli that is not true because I am still able to navigate the file. e.g. `0` and `$` work as expected.

Comment: Maybe this should be asked in https://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if you would like to interrupt current find-replace operation and resume it again. But if that is acceptable, here is my suggestion:

1. Start your find-replace the way you mentioned:
   `:%s/find/replace/gc`
2. After you accidentally skip over a substitution by pressing `n`, interrupt the search by pressing `<ctrl-C>`
3. Press `<shift-N>` to go back to the previous occurrence of your `find` term
4. Run find-replace a little differently while you are at this word: `:.,$s/find/replace/gc`
5. Continue the operation

All this functionality works with vim native capabilities without having to install any addon.

Note: The `.,$` range specifier indicates to perform `:s` (`substitute`) operation over a range of lines that start with *current* line (indicated by `.`) and until *last* line (indicated by `$`).

Note2: It might be known to you, but reiterating for anyone else who stumbles upon this post searching for something similar - The `%` range specifier indicates to perform `:s` (`substitute`) operation over *all lines* of currently active buffer.

Comment: Shocked that this is not supported, but if you must edit your previous search, you may find `q:` helpful. Documented in `:h cmdline-window`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you **can't** back to previous match using this pattern. Appeared bar propose following commands `y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y` but no one of them will return backward to previous match.

But you **can** use little **different pattern** described bellow:

- Type this `/pattern` replacing *pattern* with interested word;
- Your cursor is navigated to first occurrence, if you don't need to change it press `n` it will navigates you to the next occurrence;
- Since you understand you need to replace a word, do this by typing `cw`, this command cuts the forward word and turns you to insertion mode;
- Type in desired text on the released place and press `ESC` to switch back to command mode;
- Now again press `n` until desired occurrence;
- Since you realize that you need to change an occurrence, just press on `.` it will repeat previously mentioned actions;
- If you want to go back just use `N`.

Comment: very nice answer! i had the same issue with OP and this saved me

Answer (score 2):

This is not answer to the question, but a very good alternative. I recently discovered the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin and it improves the search /replace process dramatically.

Basically, you have the search results in a buffer and you can do all the replacements in this single buffer.

In your scenario, you first do `:CtrlSF find`, get a buffer with all the matches in all files and then you do `/find` and move with `n` over your targets and change them (of course, you can actually change only the first one and then repeat the replacement with `.`).

If you miss some target, you just hit `N` to go back to the previous result and replace it.